# The animationstart event is not firing for pseudo-elements on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css-animations, pseudo-element, dom-events

The following CSS code defines an animation for a pseudo-element `::before`:

```
#test::before {
    content: "Pseudo-element";
    animation-name: Fade-In;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

And I'm using `animationstart` event in JavaScript to log the starting of the animation. Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr5eqnmt/).

On IE11, the `animationstart` somehow isn't working. The starting of the animation isn't being logged.

But if I change the CSS code to apply the animation on the element instead, the `animationstart` event fires correctly and logs the starting of the animation on IE11. Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeb7v1yc/).

So it seems that it's the pseudo-element's problem.

How to get the `animationstart` event fire correctly for pseudo-elements on IE11?

Comment: According to the https://caniuse.com/#search=animationstart it's known issue with IE10/IE11.